# Overwriting excel columns while keeping format using pandas ( utf-8 not works)

Tags: python, excel, unicode, utf-8

I'm working with pasting df contents to excel without overwriting the original format.
df (dataframe) contents which have Unicode characters '2个蓝+2'
However, when I try to run the code, then pasted texts inside excel, the words are not supported with unique. I am wondering if my code missed something else.

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
import pandas as pd

xlApp = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = 1
xlApp.Workbooks.Open(r'c:\Chadee\test.xlsx')
xlApp.ActiveSheet.Cells(1,1).Select

df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Somu', 'Kiku', 'Amol', 'Lini'],
                         'physics': ['2个蓝+2', 222222222, 77, 78],
                         'chemistry': [84, 111111, 73, 69],
                         'algebra': [78, 88, 82, 87]})

df.to_clipboard(index=False, encoding='utf-8')

xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial()
```

[image]

Comment: Doesn't the `PasteSpecial` documentation say anything about text encoding of the contents?

Comment: It seems not much at all. My final solution is to write a VBA script inside python and map it directly to excel to do the paste special, and it works fine.